# Centering UL navigation horizontally using CSS sprite background

Tags: html, css

I have a 4 element horizontal list using a sprite image as the li background that I've been trying to get centered in the footer div.  At this point I think I'm just running in circles randomly changing styles trying to get it.  Here's the relevent CSS and HTML:

```
#footer-share-links {
    width:400px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:10px auto;
    background:#FF6666;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:36px;
}

#footer-share-links ul {
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#footer-share-links li  {
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
}
#footer-share-links li, #footer-share-links a   {
    height:36px;
}
#ftr_facebook   {left:0px;width:25px;}
#ftr_facebook   {background:url('sprites/spriteGlobal.2014-0001.png') 0 0;}
#ftr_twitter    {left:30px;width:26px;}
#ftr_twitter    {background:url('sprites/spriteGlobal.2014-0001.png') -25px 0;}
#ftr_gplus      {left:61px;width:26px;}
#ftr_gplus      {background:url('sprites/spriteGlobal.2014-0001.png') -77px 0;}
#ftr_linkedin   {left:93px;width:26px;}
#ftr_linkedin   {background:url('sprites/spriteGlobal.2014-0001.png') -51px 0;}
```

The background and border on the div are just to help me see the box.  The HTML is:

```
  <div id="footer-share-links">
    <ul>
      <li id="ftr_facebook"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li id="ftr_twitter"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li id="ftr_gplus"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li id="ftr_linkedin"><a href=""></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Using this I get a centered red box from the div, but the list elements are pushed to the left edge.  If I add margin:0 auto; to the UL it stays the same.  If I add margin-left:100px it does move it towards center, but I don't want to use a fixed value unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: JSfiddle please but removing the `float:left` AND `position:absolute` is where you should start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it, try the following CSS:

```css
#footer-share-links {
    width:400px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:10px auto;
    background:#FF6666;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:36px;
    line-height: 36px;
}

#footer-share-links ul {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#footer-share-links li  {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;  /* demo only */
    background-color: yellow; /* demo only */
}
#footer-share-links a {
    display: block; /* or inline-block */
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/yN5MP/

As suggested earlier, remove any floats and absolute positioning.

For the parent container `#footer-share-links`, set the `line-height` equal to the `height` value, that way the vertical centering takes care of itself.

On the `ul` element, make sure to zero out the margins.

Finally, on the `li` elements, use `display: inline-block` so that the width is recognized.

You can use your `id` names to specify width's on the individual `li` elements as needed.

On the `a` elements (links), use `display: block` to get make the link take up the width of the `li` element so that the link has enough active/control area.

Comment: Thank you both!  I went with Marc Audet's answer since I just happened to try that one first.

Answer (score 2):

Stripped out some of the competing properties to the bare minimum.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/9RhYM/10/)

**CSS**

```
#footer-share-links {
    width:400px;
    text-align:center; /* this centers the inline-block list items */
    margin:10px auto;
    background:#FF6666;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:36px;
}

#footer-share-links ul {
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
}
#footer-share-links li  {
    display:inline-block;
    width:26px;
    height:36px;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-25-25-6.jpg);
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Similar to my solution.  Instead of setting the height on the `li` elmeent, I set the line-height on the `ul`, but the net result is the same.  The key is to use `inline-block` on `li`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do:

```
#footer-share-links li  {
    /*margin:0 auto;*/
    display:inline-block;   // change this to inline-block
    /*float:left;*/
    text-align:center;
    /*position:absolute;*/

}

#footer-share-links ul {
    ... 
    ...
    margin: 0; // add this
}
```

Take out those I commented out, it works